# Wordpress Menu Font Failing After SSL Install

Tags: wordpress, ssl, fonts, mixed-content

The font that is supposed to be showing for my menu and home section subtitle text is called Oswald. I had no problems at all with any fonts changing before I installed my SSL into my website. Which is through Go Daddy. Called them and they could not see any errors on their end.

Things I have tried: Flush cache, changing all fonts, deactivating/reactivating all fonts in my theme options, deactivating/reactivating the theme itself.

I'm not familiar with code and have no idea where to even begin looking. I would be very grateful of any information regarding this. Thanks, Cypher.
http://cypherbeats.com

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and i found following javascript error in console.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cypherbeats.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300italic,400italic,600italic…0|&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It means, your website loads using **https** and you are trying to fetch fonts from google fonts url using **http**.

Solution : Change path of the css which would included in your theme :

From :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800|&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

To :

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800|&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing this error :) Could you please tell me how I can change this, or exactly where? Also the codes look exactly the same?

Comment: Oh never mind I see the difference.. lol Need coffee.. Do I paste this into the custom css in my theme options?

Comment: @Cypher, code is not same. Please see the difference between **href='http:** and **href='https:** , normally css includes into your current theme's header.php file.

Comment: @Cypher, no its not custom css, normally css includes into your current theme's header.php file.

Comment: Ok, how do I locate/open my header.php file? Also, thank you very much for your help thus far.

Comment: Ok, I found it on the right side in editor. (noob alert!)

Comment: @Cypher, I am not sure if css file included in header.php file. You can check your theme's files, if you are not sure what you are doing, hire wordpress developer, he can help you.

Comment: Thank you for saving my life Milap! :D It wasn't in the header.php file but the google fonts php file. Problem solved.

Comment: @Cypher , great, kindly upvote and accept my answer to make this thread complete.

Comment: Answer accepted, sadly I cannot up-vote yet as I do not have 15 reputation. lol.

Comment: @Cypher, no problem. Happy new year 2016.